# How to prevent GNU screen from clearing the screen when terminating?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I run

```
$ screen id
```

all I can see is `[screen is terminating]` message in the top of the screen. What I want to see is the output of the `id` command and the `[screen is terminating]` message. I can get his with:

```
$ TERM=vt102 screen id
```

In this case, screen(1) doesn't clear the screen, but emits many empty lines at the end, so I can scroll up and see the output of `id`.

However, I don't want to use `TERM=vt102`, because I need some more advanced terminal features.

How can I prevent screen(1) from clearing the screen when terminating?

Comment: Why are you using screen for that? Screen is a terminal wrapper, not a terminal.

Comment: @sparticvs: I'm using screen to keep the program running, and make it possible to reattach after a hangup. Hangups happen 1% of the time, the main use case is that the program runs for a couple of minutes without a hangup, and then exits (and then screen also exits).

Comment: Use `nohup` instead. You will find it easier.

Answer (score 12):

Note that `screen` is a terminal emulator. So your question is a bit like asking how can I start `xterm` from `gnome-terminal` and have what was last displayed in `xterm` visible in my `gnome-terminal` when `xterm` exits.

Now the difference between `xterm` and `screen` is that while `xterm` uses the X protocol to draw its screen, `screen` uses a host terminal.

By default, `screen` will clear the screen of its host terminal to display its own emulated terminal and where available will use the *alternate screen* (before clearing) of that host terminal, so that upon termination, it can restore the host terminal state as it was before starting.

So what you see is not `screen` clearing the screen upon leaving, but restoring the host terminal's main screen. The content of the `screen` window that was last displayed is still there on the alternate screen. With `xterm`, you can have a look at it by selecting *Show alternate screen* in the Ctrl+MiddleClick menu.

If the host terminal doesn't support an alternate screen (like vt102 ones), it obviously can't do that. Instead, it does nothing, which is basically what you want.

So, what you can do is tell `screen` that the host terminal doesn't support an alternate screen. For that, you can add to `~/.screenrc`:

```
 termcapinfo * ti=:te=
```

Which says: for all possible host terminals (`*`, matched against `$TERM`), override the `termcap/terminfo` database to say that for those terminals, the escape sequences to enter or leave the alternate screen are the empty string.

`ti` and `te` do not exactly mean *alternate screen*. From https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_node/termcap_39.html:

> - `ti` (`smcup` in `terminfo`)
>    String of commands to put the terminal into whatever special modes are needed or appropriate for programs that move the cursor nonsequentially around the screen. Programs that use termcap to do full-screen display should output this string when they start up.
> - `te` (`rmcup` in `terminfo`)
>   String of commands to undo what is done by the `ti` string. Programs that output the `ti' string on entry should output this string when they exit.

But that translates to the *alternate screen* for most terminal emulators (specically, in `xterm` it's *alternate screen* and saving/restoring of the cursor position)

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Indeed `termcapinfo * ti=:te=` does the trick. However, when I don't specify it (and keep the default), screen clears the screen upon exit (rather than restoring whatever was displayed before screen started). I want to prevent this explicit clearing from happening.