# Use altscreen like vim with screen with Ubuntu XTerm

Tags: gnu-screen, escape-characters, xterm, tput

When I exit a screen, I want to be able to return to the terminal looking as I left it. But right now, all I can do is have it clear the screen and put the terminal at the top or the bottom through modifying my `.screenrc` file.

I can get the interaction I want by doing `tput smcup; screen -S hello; tput rmcup`,
but I don't think I can easily alias or safely make it into a function*. 
How would I change my `.screenrc` file to get this behavior?

Here is what I have tried to little effect from other Stack Exchange questions:

```
termcapinfo xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@
termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*  te=\E[?1049l:ti=\E[?1049h:
termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*  te=:ti=
```

from [How to prevent GNU screen from clearing the screen when terminating?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224213/80216)

I also read [the answer to “Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?”](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)
in [the XTerm FAQ by Thomas E. Dickey](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html),
but couldn't translate it into something actionable.

Changing the term command didn't affect me and I didn't try the second part:
[Detaching from a GNU Screen suddenly clears the terminal](https://superuser.com/q/762430/354511) (on Super User).

____________ 
* I did actually try my hand at it, but I'd like some confirmation that this wouldn't break anything:

```
jscreen () {

  if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
      if [ $1 == "-r" ] || [ $1 == "-S" ]; then
        tput smcup
        screen $@
        tput rmcup
        return
      fi
  fi
  screen $@
}
```

Comment: Please don’t say `$@` without putting it in quotes: `screen "$@"`.

Comment: Shouldn't that not matter unless the argument itself has spaces in it, in which case, the user should double quote that himself, like `screen -S "help me"` to make a screen called `\`help me\``? And thanks for the code edit.

Comment: (1) Well, you’re getting the point and missing the point at the same time.  Yes, quoting is partly about preserving spaces.  And yes, of course, if the user makes a screen called `foo bar` by typing `screen -S "foo bar"` and later tries to reattach to it with `screen -r foo bar`, it won’t work.  But the point is, if they run your `jscreen` function as `jscreen -r "foo bar"`, and your function says `screen $@` (without quotes), then your function will run `screen -r foo bar`, which won’t work.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Quoting is also critical when the ``IFS`` variable has been set to something weird, or when dealing with strings that contain any of the glob characters `?`, `*` or `[`.   See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216), [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/80216), and the other questions referenced in [the \[quoting\] tag wiki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/quoting/info).